# Edit settings.xml file on Heroku

Tags: git, maven, heroku

We are building a maven project on Heroku. Github is the SCM

This project has a dependency on our private maven repository.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>archiva</id>
        <url>http://My-URL/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

The credentials for this is specified in settings.xml of local maven.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>archiva</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

When I push the code to Heroku , it requires this credentials to download the dependency jar from the private repo. On Heroku, how do I edit this file or what is the maven home location on heroku so that we can access using `heroku run bash --app Appname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/) was created mostly in order to solve this particular problem. Heroku expects you to push source code to their Git repository and let them compile it there and run. The mentioned plugin works differently. It relies on the already compiled JAR/WAR artifact and commits just `settings.xml` and `pom.xml` to Heroku Git. Then, with a help of `maven-invoker-plugin` it runs your JAR/WAR remotely.

You can use private repositories inside setting.xml - their configuration will be moved to Heroku automatically.

Comment: Also, I was going through jcabi heroku plugin. The documentation is not sufficient enough. Can documentation be extended to help developer s use the plugin